# Unable to properly fill form with array values using loop

Tags: php, html, arrays

Please I need help fixing this. I am trying to fill a form using values of array but its messing up the form.

I want to display the af_rating in the input fields

```
<?php
    $af_skill = array(12, 9, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7);
    foreach ($af_skill as $k => $row_af):
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <?php
            $af_skill_rating = array(1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4);
            foreach ($af_skill_rating as $k2 => $af_rating):
                ?>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="af_rating-<?= $row_af[$k]; ?>" value="<?php echo $af_rating[$k2]; ?>" max="5" min="1" required> <br>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

it should look like this below image 
[image: output image]

Comment: `$af_rating` is a number, there's no `[$k2]` index for it.

Comment: Just remove the index from  `<?php echo $af_rating[$k2]; ?>`

Comment: Yes, I have removed the index, but foreach loop is now 7*7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a simple array as [PHP Associative Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp).

You could use your code if you had something like this

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
foreach($age as $key => $value){
   //first time in this loop $key = Peter 
   //and $value = "35"
}
```

I changed that in your code.

```
<?php
$af_skill = array("12" => "1", "9" => "2", "6" => "5", "3" => "4", "4" => "3", "5" => "2", "7" => "4");

foreach ($af_skill as $key => $value): ?>
    <div class="form-group">


        <div class="col-sm-5">


                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="af_rating-<?php echo $key ?>"
                       value="<?php echo $value; ?>" max="5" min="1" required> <br>

        </div>


    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also check your `foreach` because you are using foreach loop inside each other so that will produce 7*7 inputs

Comment: I have used your code, but I think theres a conflict with the foreach loops. I just want for each af_skill, there should be an af_rating

Comment: Yes the foreach loops is 7*7 time and I need it just once

Comment: I replaced your arrays with one Associative array  so you can try it now.

Answer (score 1):

you have error in this line, you are using values as an array. So change this line

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="af_rating-<?= $row_af[$k]; ?>" value="<?php echo $af_rating[$k2]; ?>" max="5" min="1" required/>
```

with

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="af_rating-<?= $row_af[$k]; ?>" value="<?php echo $af_rating; ?>" max="5" min="1" required/>
```

Comment: I did that, the numbers have now displayed but it created 42 inputs instead of just 7

Comment: you have two for loops, for each outer loop the inner loop is repeating 7 times

Comment: Yes exactly, thats the problem I am facing. I want it resolved in the sense that for each af_skill, there should be a af_rating in the input field

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop twice. With your setup, the keys from one array will match the keys from the second (af_skill[0] will correspond with af_skill_rating[0]). I submit the following code:

```
<?php
    $af_skill = array(12, 9, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7);
    $af_skill_rating = array(1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4);
    foreach ($af_skill as $k => $row_af):
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="af_rating-<?= $row_af; ?>" value="<?php echo $af_skill_rating[$k]; ?>" max="5" min="1" required> <br>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```